# Electron Load Header/Footer

Tags: electron

I'm completely new to electron, but already love it!

But I just wonder how to handle an application with different pages.
I couldn't write a single .html file for each page because when something in the header changes I have to do the change in every single .html file.

Which solutions to you prefer and do you have code-snippets?

Answer (score 1):

I once created [this.](https://jsfiddle.net/mjz2xxeg/)
You can add a header outside of the `<div>`. It will be visible all the time and if you want to change the header you only have to change it once.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/ovezbn4j/

This example is a typical single page application, with a sidenav bar that allows you to artificially navigate through the application by replacing the html within the 'main' div with the appropriate content.

Since you are using Electron, I would recommend using that fiddle as a guideline as it is pure javascript.

For the actual implementation into your Electron application, you will want to fully utilize the node ecosystem, notably Angular and / or Handlebars, or any other packages with similar single page application features.

```
let getHTML = pageName => {
  switch(pageName) {
    case 'home':
      return homePage;
      break;
    case 'create-user':
      return createUserPage;
      break;
    default:
      alert(`${pageName} does not exist!`);
      break;
  }
}

let homePage = '<p>This is the home page!</p>';
let createUserPage = '<p>This is the user creation page!</p>';
```

This snippet in particular should be implemented using Handlebars by referencing and compiling .hbs files based on the navBtn id and then inserting the resulting html string into the main body.